# Filter box working fine in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: html

I have created a filter box using HTML which works fine in chrome but causes some issues in IE. Below is the code I've tried.

```
<input type="hidden" id="field_name" value="${jvar_field}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="table_name" value="${jvar_table_name}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="selected_recs" value="${jvar_selected}"/>  
<input type="hidden" id="table_query" value="${jvar_table_query}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="link_id" value="${jvar_link_id}"/> 
<h5 style="margin-bottom: 1px; padding-bottom: 0;">Filter:</h5> 
<input id="filter_text" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;" placeholder="filter" type="text"/>
<br/>
<div id="slush_holder">
    <g:ui_slushbucket/>
</div>
```

[image: Chrome output]

[image: IE output]

Comment: add your desired output or screenshot even.

Comment: Please edit your questions with screenshots.

Comment: We will need your javascript as well,  to be able to see how you deal with this;